# Catch exception for null value in a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, dataset, datatable

I have an application in C# (winforms) that uses code generated by wizards for database management (datasets, datatables, etc.). If for example I have a datacolumn configured to allow null values (property AllowDBNull = true) and when a null value is entered (in a form) is configured to throw an exception (property NullValue = ThrowException). When in a form a textfield is edited and left blank it won't let the user switch focus to another control, I think it might be because of the NullValue property to throw an exception).The question is: how can I catch the exception and set a proper value.

Comment: Put a copy of the exception that gets thrown in the question. I'm sure it will be pretty obvious once you do this.

Comment: Actually I don't know what kind of exception is thrown, the designer has that value, if I set another value in the designer I get an error. The only sympton is that when I left the textbox associated with the field I can't focus to another control.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you could use this to catch the exception but you might be able to bind an event for FocusLost or the like to check the value of the field and give it an appropriate value as mentioned in the second half of your last statement.. This might also make the need to catch the exception obsolete.

Comment: Tried that but no luck, tried also to catch the ColumnChanging event but no luck either. Any help?

Comment: If I can think of something else Ill edit my answer, but I am not a UI heavy programmer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If your controls were bound to the DataSet in the designer, try setting the `Null Value` property in the Advanced Bindings section of the control's properties to your desired value.  I imagine there is a similar way to do this in code if you set up your bindings that way.

Cheers!
JE